# How to Customize Django-allauth and templates?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-allauth

Is there any tutorial on how to customize `django-allauth` templates and fields.
I know how to use with existing allauth and add fields.
But I would like to learn about customizing templates completely like changing order and other?

Answer (score 4):

If you create a file `templates/account/login.html` with this name in your code layout, it can override the one shipped with `django-allauth`.

For social accounts `templates/socialaccount/connections.html`

Django-Allauth has some [documentation](https://docs.allauth.org/en/latest/common/templates.html#overriding-the-built-in-templates) to override templates.

**One of the options to reorder the form**

```
# yourapp/forms.py
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm
class YourSignupForm(SignupForm):
    field_order = ['email', 'username', 'password1', 'password2']

# settings.py:
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'signup': 'mysite.forms.YourSignupForm'}
```

Some example **[rendering fields manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually)**

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.email.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.email.id_for_label }}">Your email address:</label>
    {{ form.email }}
</div>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.username.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.username.id_for_label }}">Your Username:</label>
    {{ form.username }}
</div>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.password1.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.password1.id_for_label }}">Password:</label>
    {{ form.password1 }}
</div>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.password2.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.password2.id_for_label }}">Password(again):</label>
    {{ form.password2 }}
</div>
```

**Your code:**

```
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm
class MyCustomSignupForm(SignupForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100) 
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

    def save(self, request):

        user = super(MyCustomSignupForm, self).save(request)

        return user
```

**`settings.py:`**

```
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'signup': 'mysite.forms.MyCustomSignupForm'}
```

Comment: How about the changing the order of fields ?

Comment: You can define your some custom [form](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html#forms) and than reorder fields. Or by [rendering fields manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually).

Comment: Thanks. If there are any sample code, could you please post it for reference.

Comment: Can you please post full code if you have. Or can you please correct the one below....     
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm
from django import forms

class MySignupForm(SignupForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

    def save(self, request):
        user = super(MySignupForm, self).save(request)
        first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.save()
        return user
I used the save method to save it in my db.

Comment: I have added your code in my answer. Dajngo-allauth is able to add first_name and laste_name to User object (add user to your db)